# Given a set, is there another one disjoint and equipotent to the given one?

Tags: set-theory

If $X$ is a set, can we prove that there exists another set $Y$ such that $X \cap Y = \emptyset$ and $|X| = |Y|$?

I want to know if we can prove it using only the most basic axioms on ZF, that is extensionality, pair, union and replacement.

I alredy know that if we use regularity axiom we can just define $Y=X \times \{X\}$, but can it be proven without this axiom?

Comment: Maybe $X \times \{ \emptyset \}$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But how do I prove that they are disjoint?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But what if $X = \{x, (x, \emptyset)\}$?